# Dynamic Sender Profile: issue with snippet code

Tags: marketing-cloud

I'm trying to duplicate a currently working dynamic sender profile.

The original is set to:

%%[set @ValorBuscado = "FromName" Output(ContentBlockByKey("PRREU_CS_SenderProfile"))]%%

This block PRREU_CS_SenderProfile, es a snippet code that the first thing it does is a lookup on the country of the _Subscriber on my  MainContacts DE. And with that country another lookup to a DE where all the information is for each country.

The idea of the new SP is that instead of looking in the MainContacts DE, to look for the country, I esnt to look for the country in a Salesforce Data DE, and from there on the same as the original SP. This snippet is "PRREU_CS_SenderProfile_NPS"

Here is part of the code.

**ORIGINAL**

```
*set @leadOrContact = _subscriberkey

if Substring(@leadOrContact,1,3) == "003" then

set @Pais = Lookup("EFLMAE_DE_AllContacts", "Pais", "PersonContactID", @leadOrContact)

else 
set @Pais = Lookup("EFLMAE_DE_Leads", "Pais", "LeadID", @leadOrContact)

endif*
```

**NEW SP**

```
*set @Contact = _subscriberkey

set @Paisess = Lookup("JRN_NPS_Promo_B2C - 2024-03-20T021533268", "Account:R3_CON_FOR_AccShop__pc", "Account:PersonContact:Id", @Contact)

    if not empty(@Paisess) Then

        set @Paises = @Paisess

    else
        set @Paises = Lookup("JRN_NPS_Promo_B2B - 2024-03-20T044621106", "Contact:R3_CON_FOR_AccShop__c", "Contact:Id", @Contact)

    endif*
```

The result is thta the new snippet does not work. The emails get errored.
I've tested the code in the snipped as code in the email and all variables get returned correctly.

Does anybody have an idea as of why it's not working?

Thanks!

Comment: Which error did you receive?